# Can I get Teleport magicka early by blowing myself up?

Tags: magicka

I've read that you can get the Teleport magicka on top of that bridge (see screenshot) early in chapter 1 by blowing yourself up with mines and thereby launching yourself into the air and onto the bridge.

I've tried it with different mines, but I only get damages, the mines don't throw me anywhere. Is this not possible anymore or am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this video

showing how to get it, it is only usable in multiplayer mode, as you can't launch yourself with mines but only other players (if you have a second controller it is doable on a single computer though)